# Solution for linear system of matrices

Tags: matrices

Given matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$ which belongs respectively to $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m \times p}$, how does one obtain $B$ on the equation $A \, B = C$ ?

Best regards.

Comment: Easy eample: $A = (1,2)$, $C=0\in\mathbb R^{1\times 1}$. In general, if $A$ is non-square, there is either no solution or infinitely many. For the existence of a solution it is necessary that $\operatorname{im}C\subset\operatorname{im}A$.

Comment: Oh, I thank you for the answer. However, I am looking for a complete answer. In your case, the solution set is $\left\{B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}, \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \rvert \lambda \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a solution if and only if $\operatorname{im}C\subset\operatorname{im}A$. In this case, the set of solutions is given by
$$
\left\{A^\dagger C + K : \operatorname{im}K\subset\ker A\right\},
$$
where $A^\dagger\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$. This pseudo inverse has the property that
$$
AA^\dagger = P_{\operatorname{im}A}\qquad\text{and}\qquad A^\dagger A = P_{\operatorname{im}A^\top},
$$
where $P_M$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $M$.

**Proof.** Assume there exists a solution $B$. Then $ABx = Cx$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^p$. Hence $\operatorname{im}C\subset\operatorname{im}A$. Conversely, assume that $\operatorname{im}C\subset\operatorname{im}A$. Then, setting $B = A^\dagger C + K$ for some $K$ with $\operatorname{im}K\subset\ker A$, we get
$$
AB = A(A^\dagger C + K) = AA^\dagger C + AK = P_{\operatorname{im}A}C = C.
$$
Conversely, if $B$ is a solution, then apply $A^\dagger$ from the left to $AB = C$ to get $P_{\operatorname{im}A^\top}B = A^\dagger C$. Hence, for all $x$ there exists $K(x)\in\ker A$ such that $Bx = A^\dagger Cx + K(x)$. We have $K(x) = Bx - A^\dagger Cx$ for all $x$, so that $K$ is a linear map with image in $\ker A$. Thus, $B = A^\dagger C + K$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130872/discussion-on-answer-by-amsmath-solution-for-linear-system-of-matrices).